# Omit first thumb index with fancytabs package

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, thumb-index, fancytabs

In my document I would like to add a thumb index, a small rectangle on the right side. This comes in hand when browsing the printed document. I think it looks neat as well.

Eg:
[image]

There are several packages available to use for this goal. I would like to use `fancytabs`.

I got a MWE set up. However, it turns out that the TOC is considered as an chapter as well and gets a thumb index, #0, as well.

**How can I omit the first thumb index?**

The manual mentions the `\fancytabsFloor` command, which I thought was designed for this. But setting this, didn't solve it.

CTAN Package Fancytabs: https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs

MWE on Overleaf editor: https://v2.overleaf.com/5747617328trvpfsmswrhc

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% changed scrpage2 from fancytabs documentation example to the newer scrlayer-scrpage package
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancytabsHeight{1.5cm}
%\fancytabsGap{}
%Define the maximum amount of tabs on a page. After \tabcount tabs are displayed, the next tab is displayed on top of the page again.
\fancytabsCount{6}
\fancytabsLeftColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRightColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRotate{0}
\fancytabsFloor{0}

% Set central right header to display tab
% for both scrplain and scrheadings
\cohead[\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}]{\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{B chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{C chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Therefore I would declare a new layer for the chapter thumbs:

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  contents={\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}
]{fancytab.odd}
```

Then I would patch `\chapterlinesformat` to remove or add this layer to `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` for unnumbered and numbered chapters, respectively:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\ifstr{#2}{}
      {% remove the fancytab.odd if the chapter is unnumbered
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
      }
      {% add the fancytab.odd if the chapter is numbered
        \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}{}
          {\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}}%
        \IfLayerAtPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}{}
          {\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}}%
      }%
    }{}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Note: If you set one of the option `chapterprefix`, `appendixprefix`, `headings=twolinechapter` or `headings=twolineappendix, you have to patch`\chapterlineswithprefixformat` in the same way.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% changed scrpage2 from fancytabs documentation example to the newer scrlayer-scrpage package
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancytabsHeight{1.5cm}
%\fancytabsGap{}
%Define the maximum amount of tabs on a page. After \tabcount tabs are displayed, the next tab is displayed on top of the page again.
\fancytabsCount{6}
\fancytabsLeftColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRightColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRotate{0}
\fancytabsFloor{0}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  contents={\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}
]{fancytab.odd}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\ifstr{#2}{}
      {% remove the fancytab.odd if the chapter is unnumbered
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
      }
      {% add the fancytab.odd if the chapter is numbered
        \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}{}
          {\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}}%
        \IfLayerAtPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}{}
          {\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}}%
      }%
    }{}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{B chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{C chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

---

If the TOC is the first chapter and the only one which is unnumbered, then you can add the layer when the TOC is finished:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% changed scrpage2 from fancytabs documentation example to the newer scrlayer-scrpage package
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancytabsHeight{1.5cm}
%\fancytabsGap{}
%Define the maximum amount of tabs on a page. After \tabcount tabs are displayed, the next tab is displayed on top of the page again.
\fancytabsCount{6}
\fancytabsLeftColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRightColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRotate{0}
\fancytabsFloor{0}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  contents={\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}
]{fancytab.odd}

\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
  \AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{B chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{C chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

You could also define a new layer pagestyle when all settings for `scrheadings` are done. First you can clone `scrheadings`:

```
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{fancytabs}{}
```

Then you can add the layer to the new pagestyles:

```
\AddLayersToPageStyle{fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% changed scrpage2 from fancytabs documentation example to the newer scrlayer-scrpage package
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancytabsHeight{1.5cm}
%\fancytabsGap{}
%Define the maximum amount of tabs on a page. After \tabcount tabs are displayed, the next tab is displayed on top of the page again.
\fancytabsCount{6}
\fancytabsLeftColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRightColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRotate{0}
\fancytabsFloor{0}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  contents={\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}
]{fancytab.odd}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{fancytabs}{}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancytabs}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{B chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{C chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you use this new pair of pagestyles then you can remove the thumbs on part pages using `\renewcommand*\partpagestyle{plain.scrheadings}`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% changed scrpage2 from fancytabs documentation example to the newer scrlayer-scrpage package
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancytabsHeight{1.5cm}
%\fancytabsGap{}
%Define the maximum amount of tabs on a page. After \tabcount tabs are displayed, the next tab is displayed on top of the page again.
\fancytabsCount{6}
\fancytabsLeftColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRightColor{gray!50}
\fancytabsRotate{0}
\fancytabsFloor{0}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  contents={\fancytab{\color{white}\thechapter}{\thechapter}}
]{fancytab.odd}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{fancytabs}{}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.fancytabs}{fancytab.odd}

\renewcommand\partpagestyle{plain.scrheadings}% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancytabs}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{B chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{C chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, this is advanced stuff. I am not familiar with xpatch. Thanks very much for this solution.

Comment: @JohanFit I have added a version for a document with the TOC as first chapter and no other unnumbered chapter. Then there is no need to patch a command.

Comment: Unfortunately the second version doesn't apply for me. It's like you said, only if there are numbered chapters after the TOC. When you add a bibliography or glossary list, there will be numbered thumb indexes for those sections as well. Can't get the xpatch working with the theme I am using (hepthesis). Looking into a solution with fancyhdr at the moment.

Comment: I have added a third version using a new pair of layer page styles. For the first version: your class sets KOMA-option `chapterprefix`. So you have to patch `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`, ie replace `\chapterlinesformat` by `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` in the first exampgle.

Comment: Ad: when using part pages via \part , omit the thumbs on part title pages with an extra \xpretocmd `\xpretocmd\part
  {
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
        \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{fancytab.odd}%
    }{}%
 {\PatchFailed}`

Comment: If you use the third example with the new layer pagestyles, you only have to redefine `\partpagestyle` : `\renewcommand*\partpagestyle{plain.scrheadings}`.